# How to disable effect when addView in Android

Tags: android

I have a problem : When I add a `CustomView` into `FrameLayout` with some params to set CustomView position at bottom of FrameLayout. The first, `CustomView` is created with some params, and I used `addView()` function to add it to `FrameLayout`. But first `CustomView` is displayed at top of `FrameLayout`, and after that It moving(very fast) to bottom of FrameLayout.

How to disable this effect?

Comment: show the part of the code where it happens...

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the `LayoutTransition` for your view.

```
LayoutTransition layoutTransition = yourFrameLayout.getLayoutTransition();
layoutTransition.disableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.APPEARING);
```

Read more about [LayoutTransition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html) on the android developers website.